# Sending a boolean result from a button press to a redux store

Tags: react-native, redux, boolean

I am trying to parse the result of the `true` or `false` value into my Redux store. Below is the `handleSubmit` function that will send the result into the store.

```
 handleSubmit = () => {
    console.log('autoLimitChange: ', Boolean);
    if (Boolean !== null) {
        dispatch(updateAutoLimitChange(Boolean.autoLimitChange));
        navigation.navigate('Salary');
    }
}
```

The `button` action is below and will be parsed when the `handleSubmit` function is activated by pressing the button.

```
<View style={LimitStyle.autoInc}>
    <Button
        title={'Increase Limit Automatically'}
        onPress={this.handleSubmit}
        color={'#FFFFFF'}
    >
        {true}
    </Button>
</View>
<View style={LimitStyle.manInc}>
    <Button
        title={'Wait for my permission'}
        onPress={this.handleSubmit}
        color={'#20273D'}
    >
        {false}
    </Button>
</View>
```

I keep getting the error:

> `(customer.updateAutoLimitChange) is not a function`

Comment: I would like to help but this code is so wrong that I don't even know what you are trying to do.  `Boolean` is the constructor function for `boolean` values in Javascript.  It will never equal `null` and it definitely does not have a property `autoLimitChange`.  Is there some other local variable with the name `Boolean`?  Can you update your post to include the whole component?

Comment: I do not know what happened, but the coding fairies arrived while I was asleep and it worked.